# About array in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have got the problem with index of arrays;

I declare two arrays:

```
var array1:Array=["A", "B", "C"];
var array2:Array=["D", "E", "F"];
```

We have two arrays, the goal: We need to choice of the array element A, the index opened or eliminated, the corresponding array element by index A, item D.
If i choise B->E and e.t.c, I have made it task by loops but can't... I am new in ActionScript

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. If you select "A" from array1, it is removed an "D" is removed from array2? Leaving you with
array1 = ["B", "C"]
array2 = ["E", "F"]

Comment: Not remove, if i select A element of array1, the index which ->0, then i need to trace the element by index of array2, for example: A element has index 0, then i would like to trace from array2 element D, because index of the first array 0... and etc...

Comment: maybe if you explain the purpose of the application of the arrays, it can give us a better understanding of your question.

Comment: The purpose, for example: I need to trace element of array by themselves index, I select element B from array1, which has the index 1, the purpose is to trace the element by index from array1 to array2, I select B with the index 1, in array2 the index of element E is 1, and i will trace the element E

Comment: If you're selecting an item from the array with an index, then why can't you `trace` the same index of the other array? `i = 2; trace(array2[i])`

Answer (score 3):

```
trace (array2[array1.indexOf("A")]);
```

Will trace out "D". Is that what you were after? It sounds like you're looking to discover the **Array.indexOf()** function.

Comment: @The_asMan this comment made me lol because I also don't understand what he is asking for, nevertheless, I'm going to try my hand at answering it.

Comment: As long as someone answers each possible interpretation of the question, we've got it covered ;-) I'm sure it's hard sometimes for non-English speakers to get help, so I try my best to understand.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you actually want to use a Dictionary, not Arrays:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html

With a dictionary you can use "A" as the key to access element "D".

---

It's hard to tell though without seeing more of your code and/or knowing more about your use case. For example, I'm assuming that you cannot simply use the same array index for both arrays because "A" is input by a user or something.

Comment: I also thought he was describing the need for a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what your asking for, but I hope this is the answer for it:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var table:Array = [["A", "B", "C"],
                               ["D", "E", "F"]];

            traceColumn(table, 0);
            trace("\n");
            traceColumn(table, 1);
            trace("\n");
            traceColumn(table, 2);

            // output: A
            //         D
            //
            //         B
            //         E
            //
            //         C
            //         F

        }// end function

        private function traceColumn(table:Array, column:int):void
        {
            for each(var row:Array in table)
            {
                trace(row[column]);

            }// end for each

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```